# why the autoplay attribute isn't working in the video tag

Tags: html, web

[image: here is the code]

the `autoplay` attribute in the video tag isn't working & the loop attribute  isn't working and idon't know please help me

Comment: Please include the actual code, not a picture of it. That way, people can actually experiment with it to help you.
Which browser(s) does it or doesn't it work on?

Comment: Provide more useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Bertijn Pauwels' solution does not work for you, it seems that you've run into an issue that is related to your browser.

**I assume that you are running the latest version of Google Chrome**

With version 66 of Google Chrome, Google introduced a change to their browser that stops videos from autoplaying ***if they have sound enabled***

[This](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) article explains the situation in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0):

According to W3 Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_autoplay.asp

Try using just `autoplay` or `autoplay="autoplay"`

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered your problem. According to w3schools website if you use muted attribute it would be fixed.[https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_autoplay.asp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJDh0.png)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your answer to include information from your link instead of just linking. That way your answer will still be valuable if the link stops working.